# Type defines with gnu gcc compiler

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, arm

I compiled some typedefines with gnu arm-elf-gcc, flags set -02 -g. After I made a .lst file with objdump, following command-line options set  -s -S -D.

I can't find the typedefines in the listing. Not in .text nor in .data section?

```
unsigned int state_0=0x6;
typedef unsigned char uc32;

typedef struct{
     unsigned int mask;
     uc32 id;
     uc32 type;
     unsigned int attribute;
} Pin;

unsigned int state=2;

void foo(void)
{
    state=0;
    state=1;
}

void foo_1(void)
{
   Pin pin_1;

   uc32 loop=4;
   foo();
   pin_1.mask=0x5;
   state=0x07;
}
```

Comment: Compile-time definitions don't go into sections within the executable image They are not "turned" into code or data!!!

Comment: But words, half-words, bytes variables are set in data section.  And typedefines are only used by the compiler?  If I use a typedefine variable in my code, shouldn't there be some memory allocated?

Comment: You allocate `Pin` on stack, so you will not see it in any sections - you will only see it as "code" in the .text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`typedef` creates an alias for an existing type - no more; the compiler will resolve it to the *actual* type and generate code accordingly, the type name symbols do not need to appear in the final code or debug information.

Moreover a type define does not instantiate a data object, it has no location so will not appear in the link map.

Comment: Is this true for all struct, union, enum types?  Even they are not type defined.

Comment: @JoVanMontfort : Typenames in general are not objects and so not in the link map - they have no location.  It is likely that this information is included in the debug information because a debugger needs information regarding structs and enums etc, (but not necessarily typedef aliases) but how that is encoded is specific to the tool-chain.